# Add Group Member Fails with 404 Error

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

We are seeing a strange intermittent issue with some of our customers. We have a multi tenant Office app which uses Microsoft Graph to create a `Group` and add a `User` to that group.

We first hit the Create Group endpoint at `https://graph.microsoft.com/groups` and in return get the `GroupID`. Then immediately after which we hit the `https://graph.microsoft.com/groups/{groupID}/members` to add a member to the group. For few of our customers we are getting error while adding member, saying the Group was not Found.

Following is the suppressed response JSON from Add members request:

```json
"responseCode": 404,
"response": "Not Found",
"content": {
    "error": {
        "code": "Request_ResourceNotFound",
        "message": "Resource '{groupID}' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "02c8bd11-2913-40ab-a3c3-99f97357f8f7",
            "date": "2017-11-02T17:48:00"
        }
    }
}
```

Even though API throws the error, we do see the group in Office 365. If we try same API after ~10 minutes, it works fine. Most likely this is happening as Group is not yet provisioned.

Is there any property/webhook/api call we can make to be sure the Group is provisioned before performing any action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no webhook. But you can make a get call to read the group. 
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/groups/{groupId}

Replication of data from primary to secondaries will take some time(2-3 mins for cross data center replication). If you are in the same session the read request after the create should get it immediately.

Comment: Exactly that's what we found out.  We decided (not implemented) to throw "create group" call in background thread and ask our users to visit later to perform the action on group.